# How to send HTTP URL parameters in postman?

Tags: postman

How to send HTTP URL parameters in **Postman**?

```
Url: https://md.world.paas:443/data

URL parameters: key = ObjectList
```

How can I send URL parameters?

Comment: refer section URL here: https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can do it in the following ways:

- Use environment variables:

  1. click on the wheel top right [image]
  2. click on *Manage Environments*
  3. either create an environment or click on *Globals*
  4. define key-value pairs
  5. you can use the values you defined by enclosing the key in double curly brackets/braces, as you see in the image.
- Use local variables:

  1. write the variable name in the url with a ':' in front of it, as you see in the image
  2. click on the *Params* button at the right of the url
  3. fill in the value for your variable
- Use request parameters:

  1. click on the *Params* button at the right of the url
  2. fill in both key and value
  3. a request parameters string will be appended to your url in the form of 
     *?key1=value1&key2=value2*

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, what you call local variables here are called "path variables" by the Postman documentation; Postman also has a concept they call "local variables" but they are confined to scripts.

Comment: when adding variables into environment, I had to reset my Postman to see my new variables. I spent minutes debugging why my variables didnt work

Comment: need to save the environment before the variables/ new values are visibe